# Is there a convenient way to do analytics of a servlet?

Tags: logging, servlets, analytics, tracking

Traditional logfile analytics tools (awstats, statcounter) or general web analytics (google analytics, yahoo web analytics) are not suitable for analyzing traffic on servlets. Is there a good alternative to log messages using a logging framework (log4j for example) and to write a custom analytics software for these?

Comment: Can you describe what data points you want to capture that you can't get using other analytics tools? That will help focus the responses to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could write a [servlet filter](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/Filters.html) that reports analytics etc. via the platform independent [JMX monitoring infrastructure](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jmx.html)?

Comment: This sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I use [dTrace](http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/content/dtrace/), but I run on Solaris. If your on Linux they also have a similar tool [SystemTap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/). They are great for analytics and especially if you don't want to change a single line of code of your application.

Note: Both of these allow you to measure traffic with simple scripts